# openid-client parameters : return empty . what should i pass in callbackparams Method

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, openid

i am using openid client

here is code

```
const params = client.callbackParams('http://localhost:3000/auth/cb');

    console.log('params....:', params);
      
    const tokenSet = await client.callback('http://localhost:3000/auth/cb', params, { nonce });
```

parmas is empty . what should i pass in `client.callbackParams()`  method

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client/blob/v5.1.8/docs/README.md#clientcallbackparamsinput), you ought to pass the current URL including the query string parameters.

input can be `<string> | <http.IncomingMessage> | <http2.Http2ServerRequest>`

When input is of type string it will be parsed using url.parse and its query component will be returned.

When input is a GET http/http2 request object its url property will be parsed using url.parse and its query component will be returned.

When input is a POST http/http2 request object its body property will be parsed or returned if it is already an object. Note: the request read stream will not be parsed, it is expected that you will have a body parser prior to calling this method. This parser would set the req.body property.